# Button for exporting image div as png

Tags: html, html2canvas

I made basic website using ChatGPT. Could I possibly add a button that will save 9:16 1080x1920 image of image that you can see on "website"?
Image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPCqa.jpg) is preview of site when i upload image that you can see in Image [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhASb.jpg) resolute should look like Image [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnTTY.png) Simple as that, yeah i know i can screnshot, but i wanna make it simple and keep aspect ratio

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>IMG to IG</title>
    <style>
        /* Style for the image container */
        .image-container {
          right: 8px;
          width: 1080px; /* Set width to HD+ */
          height: 1920px; /* Set height to HD+ */
          display: flex;
          justify-content: center; /* Center the images horizontally */
          align-items: center;
          height: 100vh;  /*Set the container height to the full viewport height */
          position: relative; /* Set position to relative for absolute positioning of images */
          pointer-events: none;
        }
        
        /* Style for the blurred image - Image in Background */
        .image-container .blurred-image { 
          width: 1080px; /* Set width to HD+ */
          height: 1920px; /* Set height to HD+ */
          object-fit: cover; /* Scale image to desired aspect ratio by occupies all the available space */
          filter: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cfilter id='a' x='0' y='0' width='1' height='1' color-interpolation-filters='sRGB'%3E%3CfeGaussianBlur stdDeviation='4' result='b'/%3E%3CfeMorphology operator='dilate' radius='4'/%3E %3CfeMerge%3E%3CfeMergeNode/%3E%3CfeMergeNode in='b'/%3E%3C/feMerge%3E%3C/filter%3E %3C/svg%3E#a");
          pointer-events: none;
        }

        /* Style for the original image - Image in center */
        .image-container .original-image {
          width: 80%;
          position: absolute; /* Position the image absolutely */
          top: 50%; /* Position from the top */
          left: 50%; /* Position from the left */
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Center the image */
          filter: drop-shadow(15px 15px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)) ;
          pointer-events: none;
        }

      </style>

  <body>
  <input id="upload" type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="loadImage(event)">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img id="blurredImage" class="blurred-image blur-effect" >
    <img id="originalImage" class="original-image">
  </div>
   
  <script>
    // Function to load the selected image
    function loadImage(event) {
      var originalImage = document.getElementById("originalImage");
      var blurredImage = document.getElementById("blurredImage");
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(){
        originalImage.src = reader.result;
        blurredImage.src = reader.result;
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edited code with HTML2Canvas** here I used this script as it was recommended by @Parking Master. It works somehow but it makes screenshot of the full website, not just div with id "image-container" and in preview, back layer is blurred that is not being downloaded but drop-shadow seems like it is. Can someone help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Title -->
    <title>IMG to IG</title>
    <!-- Download and Include -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/1.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        /* Style for the image container */
        .image-container {
          right: 8px;
          width: 1080px; /* Set width to HD+ */
          height: 1920px; /* Set height to HD+ */
          display: flex;
          justify-content: center; /* Center the images horizontally */
          align-items: center;
          height: 100vh;  /*Set the container height to the full viewport height */
          position: relative; /* Set position to relative for absolute positioning of images */
          pointer-events: none;
        }
        
        /* Style for the blurred image - Image in Background */
        .image-container .blurred-image { 
          width: 1080px; /* Set width to HD+ */
          height: 1920px; /* Set height to HD+ */
          object-fit: cover; /* Scale image to desired aspect ratio by occupies all the available space */
          filter: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cfilter id='a' x='0' y='0' width='1' height='1' color-interpolation-filters='sRGB'%3E%3CfeGaussianBlur stdDeviation='4' result='b'/%3E%3CfeMorphology operator='dilate' radius='4'/%3E %3CfeMerge%3E%3CfeMergeNode/%3E%3CfeMergeNode in='b'/%3E%3C/feMerge%3E%3C/filter%3E %3C/svg%3E#a");
          pointer-events: none;
        }

        /* Style for the original image - Image in center */
        .image-container .original-image {
          width: 80%;
          position: absolute; /* Position the image absolutely */
          top: 50%; /* Position from the top */
          left: 50%; /* Position from the left */
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Center the image */
          filter: drop-shadow(15px 15px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)) ;
          pointer-events: none;
        }

      </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <input id="upload" type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="loadImage(event)">

  <div class="image-container" id='image-container'>
    <img id="blurredImage" class="blurred-image blur-effect" >
    <img id="originalImage" class="original-image">
  </div>

  <div id="download">
    <a id="download-link" download="screenshot.png">Download Screenshot</a>
  </div>

  <input type='button' id='but_screenshot' value='Take screenshot' onclick='screenshot();'><br/>

  <script>
    // Function to load the selected image
    function loadImage(event) {
      var originalImage = document.getElementById("originalImage");
      var blurredImage = document.getElementById("blurredImage");
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(){
        originalImage.src = reader.result;
        blurredImage.src = reader.result;
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
    }
  
  // Script for screenshot
    function screenshot(){
      html2canvas(document.getElementById("image-container")).then(canvas => {
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        var downloadLink = document.querySelector('#download-link');
        downloadLink.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        downloadLink.style.display = 'inline';
      });
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by “website”? the actual website or something named that?

Comment: Actually it is html, it could be used as website but lot of peoples would not consider it as one, and would laugh..

Comment: So you want to take a screenshot of the current view of your website, then export is as png?

Comment: Yes, but so it would be automatic via button on page

Comment: Take a look at [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/), you can convert your page to canvas, then convert the canvas to base64, then export it as png.

Comment: @ParkingMaster Thanks, i tried to include it but it work just partly so I edited post, may you look on in.

Comment: I don’t see anything wrong with your code. This is weird that it takes a screenshot of the entire page instead of just the element you selected

Comment: Actually I just realized that your class “image-container” should be an ID instead of a class. This will return null when selected and html2canvas will by default use the body. Try changing `class="image-container"` to `id="image-container"`

Comment: Okey, that helped, i will try to clean up this code and try to fix why it is not downloading blurry version

Comment: Ok, good job fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

[HTML2Canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) will take a screenshot of the selected element you want.

In this case `#image-container`, but you’ve put a class `.image-container` and an ID `#image-container` on the same element, so when selecting `#image-container` it will return `null` because the class is already in use.

By default, the **html2canvas** will use the body as the default if there is no argument for the element or it is `null`, so this is why it is taking a screenshot of the entire page.

To fix this, simply remove the class `.image-container` or change it to an ID or select it by its class.

Here’s the second script changed to work now:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Title -->
    <title>IMG to IG</title>
    <!-- Download and Include -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/1.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      /* Style for the image container */
      .image-container {
        right: 8px;
        width: 1080px; /* Set width to HD+ */
        height: 1920px; /* Set height to HD+ */
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center; /* Center the images horizontally */
        align-items: center;
        height: 100vh;  /*Set the container height to the full viewport height */
        position: relative; /* Set position to relative for absolute positioning of images */
        pointer-events: none;
      }
        
      /* Style for the blurred image - Image in Background */
      .image-container .blurred-image { 
        width: 1080px; /* Set width to HD+ */
        height: 1920px; /* Set height to HD+ */
        object-fit: cover; /* Scale image to desired aspect ratio by occupies all the available space */
        filter: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cfilter id='a' x='0' y='0' width='1' height='1' color-interpolation-filters='sRGB'%3E%3CfeGaussianBlur stdDeviation='4' result='b'/%3E%3CfeMorphology operator='dilate' radius='4'/%3E %3CfeMerge%3E%3CfeMergeNode/%3E%3CfeMergeNode in='b'/%3E%3C/feMerge%3E%3C/filter%3E %3C/svg%3E#a");
        pointer-events: none;
      }

        /* Style for the original image - Image in center */
      .image-container .original-image {
        width: 80%;
        position: absolute; /* Position the image absolutely */
        top: 50%; /* Position from the top */
        left: 50%; /* Position from the left */
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Center the image */
        filter: drop-shadow(15px 15px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
        pointer-events: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="upload" type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="loadImage(event)">

    <div class="image-container">
      <img id="blurredImage" class="blurred-image blur-effect" >
      <img id="originalImage" class="original-image">
    </div>

    <div id="download">
      <a id="download-link" download="screenshot.png">Download Screenshot</a>
    </div>

    <input type='button' id='but_screenshot' value='Take screenshot' onclick='screenshot();'><br/>

    <script>
      // Function to load the selected image
      function loadImage(event) {
        var originalImage = document.getElementById("originalImage");
        var blurredImage = document.getElementById("blurredImage");
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function() {
          originalImage.src = reader.result;
          blurredImage.src = reader.result;
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
      }
    
      // Script for screenshot
      function screenshot() {
        html2canvas(document.querySelector(".image-container")).then(canvas => {
          document.body.appendChild(canvas);
          var downloadLink = document.querySelector('#download-link');
          downloadLink.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
          downloadLink.style.display = 'inline';
        });
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```